# Terminology for the part of a business letter with the author's and typist's initials

Tags: single-word-requests, names, letter-writing

What term, if any, is used to describe the initials of the author and typist seen together at the end of a letter at the left margin, such as AB/xyz?

Comment: I doubt that there is a widely recognized term.

Answer (score 2):

They’re called the typist’s initials.

> The typist’s initials are one of the last elements of the business letter. They include the initials of the letter’s writer in all caps, followed by a slash mark or colon, and then the initials of the typist in lower case. For example, if William Shakespeare typed a letter for his manager Virginia Woolf, the typist’s initials would be: VW/ws.

https://sba.thehartford.com/business-management/marketing/business-letter-enclosure-notation/

I’ve seen a fair number of business letters, and I’ve seen these letters only on carbons, never on an original. The correspondence of a public figure would have these letters; the person who wrote the letter may be an aide rather than the person who signed it.